# What errors can Mysql INSERT IGNORE, actually ignore?

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb

I am getting some lock problems on my INNODB database recently, resulting in a very lightweight (one row update) statement being killed off due to lock contention.

I know that by using INSERT IGNORE, you can ignore constraint based errors, such as a UNIQUE KEY conflict. But can INSERT IGNORE also deal with more serious database errors such as 'Lock Wait Timeout exceeded'? 
Likewise, how would INSERT IGNORE react in the event it was killed off by mysql's deadlock resolution?

Ultimately I need to get a better understanding of which query is holding so many locks as to stop this statement succeeding. Ive already added in some debugging code to do this.

But in the meantime I would have liked to use UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY to work around this problem, but its not supported on INNODB.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe all errors are ignored. From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead.

It uses key violations as an example of an error that is ignored, but the language seems to indicate that something much wider is covered by the `IGNORE` keyword. This is consistent with other wording on that same page (emphasis added):

> REPLACE is the counterpart to INSERT IGNORE *in the treatment of new rows that contain unique key values that duplicate old rows*: The new rows are used to replace the old rows rather than being discarded.

In other words, *if* the ignored error is a unique key constraint violation, then the REPLACE part of the statement is executed. This suggests (to me, at least) that other errors, while also being ignored, won't trigger execution of the REPLACE clause.